# Retrieve environment variables of a QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

I want to run an environment script within a QProcess and then read the environment (as a QStringList) to start other scripts with this environment.

If I start the env script and read the environment, I always get an empty QStringList. Is there a way to read out the environment of a QProcess?

I also tried to first start the environment script and the start the actual script on the same QProcess object but that did not help either.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to use `QProcessEnvironment` for what you are attempting. Some code snippets would probably clarify the problem with your implementation.

Comment: Ok, some code:
[code]
void runScript(const QString& envScript, const QString& script)
{
    QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
    proc->start(envScript); // contains something like "set ENV_VAR="env"
    proc->waitForFinished();

    proc->start(script);  // I'd expect that the environment from the env script is still set, but it is not
}
[/code]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are able to rewrite the script which sets the environment in C++ you can create the environment yourself and set it using
[void `QProcess::setProcessEnvironment ( const QProcessEnvironment & environment )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment)
method as in the example given in the method's documenation:

```
 QProcess process;
 QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
 env.insert("TMPDIR", "C:\\MyApp\\temp"); // Add an environment variable
 env.insert("PATH", env.value("Path") + ";C:\\Bin");
 process.setProcessEnvironment(env);
 process.start("myapp");
```

UPDATE

If you can't use the above method you could try using cmd.exe like this;

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
    proc->start("cmd.exe /c \"call env.bat && script.bat\"");

    return app.exec();
}
```

Having env.bat with this contents

```
set abc=test
```

and script.bat with this contents

```
echo %abc% > a.txt
```

running the above creates a.txt file with this contents

```
test
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this won't work because the script is auto-generated by a build management system and can change all the time. I could try to parse the file and find the the variables but thats not easy because the script can contain "if else" statements etc.

Comment: @Nick: Make the last line of the script "`printenv`", then parse its output instead of the script itself.

Comment: thanks for your help! @Ben Voigt: I wrote a little parser for the script itself because I don't want to change the script, but your solution could work as well.
@Piotr Dobrogost: I tried that and it works! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't used QProcess's setEnvironment method, then the empty QStringList is the expected output. For this case, QProcess uses the program's environment. To get this,

```
QStringList env(QProcess::systemEnvironment());
```

should work.

Comment: This returns the environment of the caller (the qt program that starts the QProcess). I need the environment of the QProcess after I started a environment script.

Comment: @Nick: What do you mean by "environment script"? Is your QProcess a shell?

Comment: It's a batch file like:
<code>
set TMP_DIR="..."
set REP_ACTIVE=".."
</code>
the actual script starts other processes that need this environmet to be set

Answer (score 0):

You can read all environment variables set in the QProcess in a nicer format the following way (to the standard debug output window). It will print each variable in new line.

```
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();

qDebug() << "All variables";

QString env_variable;
QStringList paths_list = env.toStringList();

foreach( env_variable, paths_list )
    qDebug() << env_variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to accomplish it without parsing external files; in my case i need to execute vcvarsall.bat from different msvc versions, and need to capture the complete environment after calling them (individually):

1. i write a .cmd script to disk which calls anything that modifies the environment;
2. ... last line of the cmd script is simply "set"
   i.e.

   > ```
   > call ...\vc\vcvarsall.bat
   > call may\be\another.cmd
   > echo {5c131c2a-405b-478a-8279-9dff52c31537}
   > set
   > ```
3. after running the script with `QProcess` i use `readAllStandardOutput()` to gather all the output.
4. whatever the output contains, after splitting it at the guid that was used as anchor, the rest is simply the full environment that the calls before had created
5. ... now i can parse it line by line as key=value parts and insert them into a new `QProcessEnvironment` (as already mentioned), and can apply it to new processes as is or with additional modifications.